**Hidden symbols**
What's hidden in the puzzle below?
            ___MARINE
            ____ ZONE
            _____ UP
            RIGHT ___
            ______'_ GREETINGS
            _______ CROSSED
            WOLF ____
            WEEK____
            BASE____
            ____ _CORE
          


The hidden things are

 DIGITS!

Each blank can be filled

 with a word to make a common phrase. Some are somewhat ambiguous (and can be disambiguated later), but things like SEASONS (GREETINGS), FINGERS (CROSSED), and (WOLF) PACK are the only sensible options for their blanks.

 After a few words are determined, the pattern can be found; each of these new words also makes a phrase with a number! The full list is:

 SUB(MARINE); SUBZERO
 TIME (ZONE); ONE-TIME
 HANDS (UP); TWO-HANDS
 (RIGHT) WAY; THREE-WAY
 SEASON(')S (GREETINGS); FOUR SEASONS
 FINGERS (CROSSED); FIVE FINGERS
 (WOLF) PACK; SIX-PACK
 (WEEK)DAYS; SEVEN DAYS
 (BASE)BALL; EIGHT-BALL
 LIVE S(CORE); NINE LIVES


Well done! For the third row it was intended to be interpreted as what the police says to suspects, but yours works too ofc. And the final answer our "fingers".

I edited this to more correctly correspond to the op’s intentions as stated here.
